# FireFox scroll bar

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

guys is there a way to customize the scroll bar in Firefox i tried using a similar technique on chrome , but i guess it's only work for chrome , after doing some research i figured out that there is no way to customize it on Firefox using this method because of a bug in the engine, so i am looking for an alternative and clean way to do it

```
 ::-moz-scrollbar {
        width: 12px;
    }
    /* Track */

     ::-moz-scrollbar-track {
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    /* Handle */

     ::-moz-scrollbar-thumb {
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: rgb(0, 62, 132);
       -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

     ::-moz-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
        background: rgb(0, 153, 255);
    }
```

Comment: https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/ You'll have to make your own scrollbar to get a consistent experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, customizing scrollbars via CSS is only implemented for webkit based browsers.

As an alternative I recommend [NiceScroll](https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/), a jQuery plugin that allows you to customize (at least a bit) the scrollbar on every (if not, at least a vast majority of them) browser.

Comment: yeah i guess i will have to use plugin since there is no way to customize it via CSS

Comment: You can still apply it first, then inspect the DOM and find the parts related to the scrollbar and customize them in CSS.